# AEC Speex . How does it work?

Tags: adaptive-filters

I'm working with AEC of Speex. The algorithm is based on the MDF adaptive filter + an adaptive learning rate. I'm using it like a ANC and it works very well.
Does anybody have some material, as block scheme, data flow diagram of the AEC of Speex.
I have read the documentation but it is not very useful for the dsp concepts.
thank you so much
m

Comment: Have you seen the matlab implementation? From this you might be able to figure out what's going on. https://github.com/wavesaudio/Speex-AEC-matlab/blob/master/speex_mdf.m

Comment: Hi ! Yep ! In my opinion the matlab implementation is NOT the same of the of the mdf.c file. I have try with different file in input and the matlab version do NOT work, the c code yes.

Comment: Have you had a look at this? http://ijset.com/ijset/publication/v2s10/IJSET_2013_1018.pdf (and, of course, at the original paper by Soo and Pang)?